# Undefined method pluck for array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this data stucture:

```
+[#<Folder id: 1, name: "mollitia", parent_id: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59", updated_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59">,
+ #<Folder id: 2, name: "porro", parent_id: 1, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59", updated_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59">, 
+ #<Folder id: 3, name: "omnis", parent_id: 2, user_id: 1, created_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59", updated_at: "2014-06-27 16:00:59">]
```

which is returned by `self.ancestors`
can I pluck its names?

```
def pwd
    self.ancestors.pluck(:name)
end
```

The above results in

```
undefined method `pluck' for #<Array:0x007ff4da780290>
```

Update

Awesome Print of the structure:

```
[
    [0] #<Folder:0x007fd2946a5f18> {
                :id => 3,
              :name => "blanditiis",
         :parent_id => 2,
           :user_id => 1,
        :created_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00
    },
    [1] #<Folder:0x007fd2946ad1c8> {
                :id => 2,
              :name => "neque",
         :parent_id => 1,
           :user_id => 1,
        :created_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00
    },
    [2] #<Folder:0x007fd2946b80c8> {
                :id => 1,
              :name => "ut",
         :parent_id => nil,
           :user_id => 1,
        :created_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00,
        :updated_at => Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:04:02 UTC +00:00
    }
]
```

Comment: What is self.ancestors? Is it an array or an association?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I'd say it's an array of objects returned by the association but I'm not 100% sure what you mean :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pluck` is used with rails to change the association query against the database. It will change it from `SELECT *` to `SELECT [attr]` where `[attr]` is the argument to pluck. Since it's an array, you can't use it. You should instead use regular old `map` from ruby. In your case, it would look something like:

```rb
def pwd
  self.ancestors.map(&:name)
end
```

Comment: In the interest of completeness - `&:name` is a shortcut for `Symbol#to_proc`, which is a way of saying: `.map { |ancestor| ancestor.name }`

Comment: Also - Rails 5 is going to include `pluck` in `Enumerable`, so this will be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

`pluck` was added to Enumerable with Rails 5, so this would indeed be obsolete https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20339

However, I think it best practice to change the returned `Array` to an ActiveRecord Relation